# How to cancel a multi instance task with a derived completion condition

Tags: alfresco, activiti, bpmn, camunda

[image]

If I have a process looking similar to this, where there is a Approve usertask and a multiinstance parallel Review usertask. The business rule is whenever the Approver approves, then even if there are more reviewers available to review the (multi)task it should cancel all the remaining task instances. `(Ex: <completionCondition>${approved == true}</completionCondition>)`. How should I implement this scenario? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could add a signal boundary event on the Multi instance Review user task. After the approve user task you can add an intermediate signal throw event that triggers the signal boundary event. In that way the Review multi instance user task will be terminated when the Approve user task is completed.

Answer (score 2):

One word of warning when using the signal approach (which is IMO the right answer).
But, notice in the below image I am splitting the flow with a parallel gateway. If I simply use a parallel join, the process instance will never complete because the parallel join never gets all the tokens it expects. You should use an inclusive join (as shown below) which will recalculate the number of expected tokens and allow flow through to the "Done" task.
[image]